# Cannot connect to a redis instance from app engine VPC connector

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, redis, google-compute-engine, google-vpc

I have an app on app engine (standard) deployed and I'm trying to connect to a redis instance I have deployed on a regular compute engine VM that I have in a VPC. I created a VPC connector as the [steps](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/connecting-vpc) said and I've my `app.yaml` file accordingly. However when the app tries to connect to the redis instance (using it's internal IP) the requests time out. Why is this happening and how can I troubleshoot it?

The part I added in the `app.yaml` looks like this:

```
vpc_access_connector:
  name: "projects/[PROJECT_ID]/locations/[REGION]/connectors/[CONNECTOR_NAME]"
```

Comment: Did you add a firewall rule to the VPC that allows [TCP connections to the port 6379](https://redis.io/topics/protocol#networking-layer)? The following command should suffice to accomplish this: `gcloud compute firewall-rules create NAME --network default --allow tcp:3128` (change NAME to the name you want for the Firewall Rule) if the Serverless VPC Access connector is attached to the [default VPC network](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#default-network).